# SSRS 2016 Printing not responding

Tags: reporting-services, printing, ssrs-2016

I have encoutnered the following problem.

In SSRS 2016 Toolbar, the print widget is not working when I am trying to print a report. However, I can still save the file to .pdf or .xls format, open the file and print it. ClientPrinting is enabled on the report server. Can anyone help? Appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried to print with another browser?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The issue has been resolved. A specific patch was not installed on the server.

Comment: You are welcome Gary. Nice to know the solution about it.

Comment: @GaryJ.Li - Could you please specify what you did to fix it? We're having the same problem. You could post what you found as an answer to your own question.